# SQL-All clients should receive atleast particular mail

Tags: sql

I need to check that there should be no client in my #Personal table who has not received ABC email.

I am writing using self join.. is it correct way or I should simply write subquery?

my table has list of client ids and email send details.(like email code,event date)

```
Select 
*
from #Personal a
join #Personal b
on a.id=b.id
where  b.emailcode<> 'ABC'
```

or

```
select * from #Personal 
where a.id in (select id from #personal where b.emailcode <>'ABC')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * 
FROM #Personal a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM #Personal b 
                  WHERE a.id=b.id
                  AND b.emailcode = 'ABC')
```

If the `ID` column is NOT NULLable can you can also use

```
SELECT * FROM #Personal 
where id NOT IN (select id from #personal 
                 where emailcode = 'ABC')
```

Comment: I think this is wrong, why: it should be like                                                              select * from #Personal A where NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from #Personal B where a.id=b.id and b.emailcode <> 'ABC'). please comment

Comment: @nancyarora I am using `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` hence it will be `emailcode = 'ABC'` , I believe you are after the list of people who hasnt received a particular email??? if thats the case then this should work.

Comment: as per my data understanding , then it will return all the ids who have not received ABC but hae received say other email code like CD, EF,GH for example.

Comment: well your understanding is wrong, the query will only look for Email type `ABC` if the user hasnt received it , it will return that user, it will not even bother to look at the other email types. Instead of guessing could you please run the query on your database and see what it brings back.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M.Ali for making me understand, I will try this and let you know the results, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of people who have not receive such an email using `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.id
from #Personal p
group by p.id
having sum(case when p.emailcode = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

An alternative form of the `having` clause is:

```
having max(case when p.emailcode = 'ABC' then 'ABC' end) is null
```